# Javascript file not being found when using Factory to call servlets

Tags: angularjs, factory

Ok i have a series of servlets within my project

If i call a servlet like so:

```
$scope.register=function()
    {
         $http({
             method : 'POST',
             url : './registration',
             data : "role=" + $scope.role+"&name=" + $scope.name + "&salary=" + $scope.salary+"&username=" + $scope.username + "&phone=" + $scope.phonenumber+
             "&password=" + $scope.pass + "&add=" + $scope.additional,
             headers : {
                 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             }
         }). success(function(data) {

                alert("changed");

           }).
           error(function(data) {
              alert("Servlet Call Error");
              $scope.message="Servlet call error";
         });
    }
```

It works however if i use a factory i get 404 not found

```
app.factory('employeeFactory', function($http){
return {editServlet: function(scope, http,toChange,changeTo) {
     $http({
         method : 'POST',
         url : './editInformationServlet',
         data : 'username=' + scope.editEmp + '&toChange=' + toChange+'&changeTo='+changeTo,
         headers : {
             'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
     }). success(function(data) {


       }).
       error(function(data) {

     });
}
```

I use route provider to go to another page, could that be the problem?
Or is it something else? i really need help my job is on the line

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the "." in front of the URLs. You should use absolute URLs, starting with "/".

Comment: ive tried using absolute urls. At least i thought it wouldve been correct. Its in src/com.peterson.database.servlet/servletName

Comment: What are you doing? The servlet URL is mapped in the web.xml (or with the `@WebServlet` annotation in the Servlet 3.0 API). It has nothing to do with the source file.

Comment: Show me your web.xml file.